# custom folium/leaflet map not rendering in jupyter notebook

Tags: leaflet, jupyter, folium

I have done the following with my tileset within a Jupyter notebook.

```
tileset = './output/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
m = folium.Map(tiles=tileset,zoom_start=1,max_zoom=4,min_zoom=1, attr='Test',no_wrap=True)
```

It renders the window but the image does not appear. When I do m.save('test.html') and open the html file in Chrome it renders just fine. Is there something else I am meant to do in the notebook to get it to render properly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have defined a map object, but did not ask to print it

Comment: Putting `m` doesn't not print the map either.

Comment: Did you resolve this? I'm having the same issue

Comment: No I didn’t. Still and issue. Feel free to upvote. :)

Comment: Don't know the solution yet, but using Firefox instead of Chrome worked for me. Maybe the file is too heavy and Chrome refuses to load it.

Comment: No resolution yet.

Comment: Same issue with me (in Chrome). I found that I had to reduce the number of rows (filtering) to get it to work in Jupyter. Maybe that is it?